# Zabbix tries to connect to the wrong database

Tags: zabbix

I have installed Zabbix on a CentOS 7 remote server, but I can't get it running.

I took a look at `/var/log/zabbix/` and I get the following error:

```
1951:20190116:044530.834 [Z3001] connection to database 'zabbix' failed: [1045] Access denied for user 'zabbix'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Now, the problem is that I DO have a database for zabbix, but it is named `zabbixdb`, not `zabbix` (as in the error message)

I tried to re-run the setup page and entered `zabbixdb`, but still nothing. Also, the `/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php` is correctly configured

```
global $DB;

$DB['TYPE']     = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']   = '127.0.0.1';
$DB['PORT']     = '0';
$DB['DATABASE'] = 'zabbixdb';
$DB['USER']     = 'zabbixuser';
$DB['PASSWORD'] = '[my_pass_here]';

// Schema name. Used for IBM DB2 and PostgreSQL.
$DB['SCHEMA'] = '';

$ZBX_SERVER      = '127.0.0.1';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = 'SV Zabbix Server';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;
```

I doubled checked and `zabbixdb` DOES exist and user `zabbixuser` has all the privileges over it.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `zabbixdb`.* TO 'zabbixuser'@'localhost'
```

What others reasons could be? Somehow zabbix has access, because it has created tables in the `zabbixdb`, but can't use them.

---

EDIT: The Solution

As it turns out, I followed the tutorial's instructions blindly. Thank you @Zatarra for the solution.

My problem was that when I wrote the DB's credentials, I wrote them exactly at the top of the file, while they where also present at a lower level, and thus, when read, were overwritten in memory.

I solved this by modifying the variables present at the lower level in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to restart the service and check if it still tries to use the zabbix database in the logs. If it does check if you have duplicate DBName entries in `zabbix_server.conf`

```
grep DBName /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf
```

And are you getting the error for zabbix web or for zabbix server? As far as I see you are pasting the web configuration, maybe you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: What would be the exact difference between `web` and `server`?

Comment: The web zabbix refers to the website where you have the dashboard while the server refers to zabbix server.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I will be checking in a few minutes and come back with updates

Comment: I did find something, and I'm working on it right now.
The tutorial that I'd followed told be to add DBName, DBUsername etc in the file, but I added them at the top. As I have discovered now, they are also present somewhere else in the file, at a lower level. I'm editing the file as I speak. Will update soon the status